# Scatter tooltip of highchart is not being displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I have a highchart of scatters and bars . I am unable to view tooltip of a scatter point which is over bar... here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tZ9Rt/

I am using these two series:

```
series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        index:2,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        name: 'Temperature'
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        index:1,
        data: [220,220,220,220,120,220,220,220,220,220,220,220],
        name: 'Rainfall'
    }]
```

Any help is highly appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Make your `tooltip` shared, and change the series `type` to `'line'` and `lineWidth` to `0`.  Then you'll have a "line" chart that looks like a scatter plot, but tooltips work!

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true //make the tooltip accessible across all series
},
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        lineWidth: 0 //make the lines disappear
    }
},
series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Column Data',
    data: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
}, {
    type: 'line', //this is a 'fake' scatter plot
    name: 'Pseudo-scatter',
    data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}]
```

Comment: awesome! that's the out-off-the-box thinking!

Answer (score 1):

It is known bug, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/923

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are unable to view the tooltip for the scatter points over the bar is because the bar gains focus before the scatter point.  The bar will maintain the focus of the tooltip until the mouse is no longer over the bar.  You could always use a shared tooltip like in this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ9Rt/1/).  By doing so it will show all the data associated with the category your mouse is hovering over.  Here is the relevant code:

```
tooltip: {
  shared: true            
},
```

Comment: The linked example doesn't work if you change the series type to scatter as the OP needs.